# Add single record to mongo collection with meteor

Tags: mongodb, meteor, collections

I am a new user to JavaScript and the meteor framework trying to understand the basic concepts. First of all I want to add a single document to a collection without duplicate entries.

```
this.addRole = function(roleName){
   console.log(MongoRoles.find({name: roleName}).count());

   if(!MongoRoles.find({name: roleName}).count())
      MongoRoles.insert({name: roleName});
}
```

This code is called on the server as well as on the client. The log message on the client tells me there are no entries in the collection. Even if I refresh the page several times.

On the server duplicate entries get entered into the collection. I don't know why. Probably I did not understand the key concept. Could someone point it out to me, please?

**Edit-1:**
No, autopublish and insecure are not installed anymore. But I already published the MongoRoles collection (server side) and subscribed to it (client side). Furthermore I created a allow rule for inserts (client side).

**Edit-2:**

Thanks a lot for showing me the meteor method way but I want to get the point doing it without server side only methods involved. Let us say for academic purposes. ;-)

Just wrote a small example:

Client:

```
Posts = new Mongo.Collection("posts");

Posts.insert({title: "title-1"});
console.log(Posts.find().count());
```

Server:

```
Posts = new Mongo.Collection("posts");

Meteor.publish(null, function () {
  return Posts.find()
})

Posts.allow({
 insert: function(){return true}
})
```

If I check the server database via 'meteor mongo' it tells me every insert of my client code is saved there.

The log on the client tells me '1 count' every time I refresh the page. But I expected both the same. What am I doing wrong?

**Edit-3:**

I am back on my original role example (sorry for that). Just thought I got the point but I am still clueless. If I check the variable 'roleCount', 0 is responded all the time. How can I load the correct value into my variable? What is the best way to check if a document exists before the insertion into a collection? Guess the .find() is asynchronous as well? If so, how can I do it synchronous? If I got it right I have to wait for the value (synchronous) because I really relay on it.

Shared environment (client and server):

```
Roles = new Mongo.Collection("jaqua_roles");

Roles.allow({
    insert: function(){return true}
})

var Role = function(){

this.addRole = function(roleName){      

    var roleCount = Roles.find({name: roleName}).count();
    console.log(roleCount);

    if(roleCount === 0){

        Roles.insert({name: roleName}, function(error, result){
            try{
                console.log("Success: " + result);
                var roleCount = Roles.find({name: roleName}).count();
                console.log(roleCount);
            } catch(error){

            }
        });
    }
};

this.deleteRole = function(){

};
}

role = new Role();
role.addRole('test-role');
```

Server only:

```
Meteor.publish(null, function () {
  return Roles.find()
})
```

Comment: Is the `autopublish` package installed? Try using `meteor list` in your terminal to find out.

Comment: I follow what @BraveKenny asked and plus add my question about the `insecure` package. Try finishing the tutorial online [here].(https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/blaze/creating-an-app) Everything will be more clear after that

Comment: Sorry for the missing information. No, autopublish and insecure are not installed anymore. But I already published the MongoRoles collection (server side) and subscribed to it (client side). Furthermore I created a allow rule for inserts (client side).
Thanks for the hint. I already did this tutorial and thought I got the point. But obviously I didn't. As far as I understood the client database and server database should be in sync with each other if I implement the same function on both sides. But I don't know why it isn't in my case. Worse, why are more than one entry added to the server db?

Comment: Hard to tell what's going on without more code. Where are you calling the `addRole` function?

Comment: Added another example to my question. I just want to add some values to a collection. Afterwards the client and the server database should have the same values. In the next step I want to perform some options checking based on the values in the client database.

I got confused doing it the asynchronous  way (Meteor.methods). If I do so I am not able to get return values in time and everything get messed up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Meteor's `insert/update/remove` methods (client-side) are not a great idea to use. Too many potential security pitfalls, and it takes a lot of thought and time to really patch up any holes. [Further reading](https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/meteor-methods-client-side-operations/) here.

I'm also wondering where you're calling `addRole` from. Assuming it's being triggered from client-side only, I would do this:

### Client-side Code:

```
this.addRole = function(roleName){
  var roleCount = MongoRoles.find({name: roleName}).count();

  console.log(roleCount);

  if (roleCount === 0) {
    Meteor.call('insertRole', roleName, function (error, result) {
      if (error) {
        // check error.error and error.reason (if I'm remembering right)
      } else {
        // Success!
      }
    });
  }
}
```

How I've modified this code and why:

1. I made a `roleCount` variable so that you can avoid calling `MongoRoles.find()` twice like that, which is inefficient and consumes unneeded resources (CPU, disk I/O, etc). Store it once, then reference the variable instead, much better.
2. When checking numbers, try to avoid doing things like `if (!count)`. Using `if (count === 0)` is clearer, and shows that you're referencing a number. Statements like `if (!xyz)` would make one think this is a boolean (true/false) value.
3. Always use `===` in JavaScript, unless you want to intentionally do a loose equality operation. [Read more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness) on this.
4. Always use open/closed curly braces for `if` and other blocks, even if it contains just a single line of code. This is just good practice so that if you decide to add another line later, you don't have to then wrap it in braces. Just a good practice thing.
5. Changed your database insert into a Meteor method (see below).
6. Side note: I've used JavaScript (ES5), but since you're new to JavaScript, I think you should [jump right into ES6](http://exploringjs.com/es6/). ES is short for ECMAScript (which is what JS is based on). ES6 (or ECMAScript 2015) is the most recent stable version which includes all kinds of new awesomeness that JavaScript didn't previously have.

### Server-side Code:

```
Meteor.method('insertRole', function (roleName) {
  check(roleName, String);

  try {
    // Any security checks, such as logged-in user, validating roleName, etc

    MongoRoles.insert({name: roleName});
  } catch (error) {
    // error handling. just throw an error from here and handle it on client
    if (badThing) {
      throw new Meteor.Error('bad-thing', 'A bad thing happened.');
    }
  }
});
```

Hope this helps. This is all off the top of my head with no testing at all. But it should give you a better idea of an improved structure when it comes to database operations.

### Addressing your edits

Your code looks good, except a couple issues:

- You're defining `Posts` twice, don't do that. Make a file, for example, `/lib/collections/posts.js` and put the declaration and instantiation of `Mongo.Collection` in there. Then it will be executed on both client and server.
- Your `console.log` would probably return an error, or zero, because `Posts.insert` is asynchronous on the client side. Try the below instead:

.

```
Posts.insert({title: "title-1"}, function (error, result) {
  console.log(Posts.find().count());
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the general hints. They seem helpful to me. Thanks for the Meteor.methods examples as well. But I want to do it the other way as well. Added some code to my question. Could you maybe have a look on it?

Comment: I appreciate your help very much! Thank a lot for your effort and hinting me to the asynchronous point and the need to use a call back function. All together did it for me. Of course I have to get the error if I want to see it.

Comment: Tried to get the thing running with your code example but was not successful. My count variable never change it value other then 0 and I don't know why. Could you help me one more time, please?

Comment: Sorry you're still having trouble. I can help, but I need to see *all* of the code, because there could be something really simple tripping you up somewhere. Go to [MeteorPad](http://meteorpad.com) and copy your code into the appropriate corresponding panes (there's common/shared code, client only, server only, etc). Once you've duplicated your project there, let me know.